# Not getting Local/Device contact name and type using AccountManager android

Tags: android, android-contacts, accountmanager

```
/**
 * Get All Account available in Phone and add into list
 */
private void getAllAccounts() {
    int counter = 0;
    final AccountManager accManager = AccountManager
            .get(Activity.this);
    final Account accounts[] = accManager.getAccounts();

    for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Name " + accounts[i].name + ", Type "
                    + accounts[i].type);
    }
}
```

I am using the above code for getting all the available accounts of the device. It works very well on Sony device but not in Samsung, Micromax, HTC. Don't know what is the reason behind this. If anyone has any idea please kindly help me.

**I AM NOT ABLE TO GET LOCAL/PHONE/DEVICE CONTACT NAME AND TYPE FOR SAMSUNG, HTC, MICROMAX.**

Answer (score 0):

do something like this

```
private String[] getAccountNames() {
    mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] accounts = mAccountManager.getAccountsByType(
            GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    String[] names = new String[accounts.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        names[i] = accounts[i].name;
    }
    return names;
}
```

for more visit

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html

Comment: by this code it will only return google accounts. I am getting those details but I am not getting Local contact name and type in Samsung. IN SAMSUNG PHONE WHEN YOU INSERT NEW CONTACT IT WILL SHOW DEVICE AS OPTION THAT I AM NOT GETTING.